# Compare row to column between tables

Tags: abap

I got a question: is it possible to compare rows with columns in ABAP? If so, how to achieve that?

Imagine we have a table like this one, where column has a number inside its name:

| FNCURR01 | FNCURR02 | FNCURR03 | FNCURR04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HWBAS | HWSTE | HWBAS | HWBAS |
| HWBAS | HWSTE | HWBAS | HWBAS |

And we got another table which looks like this:

| layout | type | column number | text of column to add to another internal table |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JC_REP03 | S | 1 | Tax Amount 19% |
| JC_REP03 | P | 2 | Tax Amount 19% |
| JC_REP03 | P | 3 | Tax Amount 9% |
| JC_REP03 | S | 4 | Tax Amount 23% |

I want to get the values from column FNCURRXX, where XX it's a value of an row of column: "column number" of another table.

For example: FNCURR01 matches the number 1 in my second table, so i get the value HWBAS.

Is it possible to achieve that dynamically? What I meant by that is that I do not want to create another table and map it somehow by hand in se11.

Comment: I didn't get your example of going from `FNCURR01` to `HWBAS`. Of course, I see it, but I'm sure you missed something in your example. Could you complete it please?

Comment: When there is a match between the column FNCURR01 and column number from my second table (in that case it will be 1), i want to fetch the data from a column fncurr01.
I wrote those tables by hand here, but in sap those tables are: /CEECV/rofirlay and /CEECV/rofirfums.

Comment: Thanks. So you want to access a component of structure by name known only at runtime (i.e. `assign component (fieldname) of structure struct to <fs>`, `loop at ... where (dynamicwhere) ...`, there could be many different answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use field symbol and assign field dynamicly.

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <lv_value> TYPE any.
    
READ TABLE table1 INDEX 1.
LOOP AT table2.
  ASSIGN COMPONENT |FNCURR0{ table2-columnnumber }| OF STRUCTURE table1 TO <lv_value>.
  WRITE <lv_value>.
ENDLOOP.
```

If you want to use first table as master you can use below example:

```
DATA: lo_descr TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr,
      ls_comp  TYPE abap_compdescr,
      lv_name  TYPE abap_compname,
      lv_i     TYPE i.

lo_descr ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( table1 ).

LOOP AT lo_descr->components INTO ls_comp.
  lv_name = ls_comp-name.
  REPLACE 'FNCURR' WITH '' INTO lv_name.
  lv_i = lv_name.
  READ TABLE table2 WITH KEY columnnumber = lv_i.
  CHECK sy-subrc IS INITIAL.
  WRITE:/ table2-columnnumber.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: [There is a new syntax for this in release 757](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/abapassign_dynamic_components.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_1@1@). `ASSIGN table1-(|FNCURR0{ table2-columnnumber }|) TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<lv_value>).`

Comment: It works for one case but the main question is: if it's possible to make it work for every match? column number 2 : FNCURR02, 3: FNCURR03 etc. I got like 60 columns and even more rows in that second table, most of them has some values :/.

Comment: I added look for Table2, so it will work for all rows in table2. I understand that you want to use table2 as base table and dynamically find HWBAS/HWSTE values.

Comment: Yes, that is correct :) So in ls_comp structure i should find the information i need.

Comment: I tried to implement that fragment of code but in one line i get an error:  `lo_descr ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( table1 ).`  The type of `lo_descr` has to match the `cl_abap_typedescr` ?

Comment: you need to put the internal table variable. if you have different type of variable you can check other methods on CL_ABAP_TYPEDESCR.